# Unable to move and animate an ImageView along a path in Android using ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas, objectanimator

I'm trying to move an `ImageView` along a `path` using `ObjectAnimator`. I'm facing an `NPE`. Here's the code I'm trying.

```
path = new Path();
path.moveTo((float)(maxX/2)+(maxX/4),maxY/4);
path.quadTo((float)(maxX/2)+(maxX/4),maxY/4, (float)(maxX/2)+(maxX/4)+30,maxY/2);

ObjectAnimator animator = new ObjectAnimator();
        animator.ofFloat(img,View.X,View.Y,path);
        animator.setDuration(1000);
        animator.setStartDelay(600);
        animator.start();
```

The `exception` is :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.initAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:534)
at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.initAnimation(ObjectAnimator.java:880)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentFraction(ValueAnimator.java:610)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:589)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1106)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1117)
at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:852)
at com.example.user.curveanimation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

If there's anything I'm doing wrong, Can somebody please help me animate via a path. SOmebody, Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have animated ImageButton1

```
TranslateAnimation a = new TranslateAnimation(0, amountToMove, 0, 0);
                            a.setDuration(1000);

                            // Finalize movement when animation ends
                            a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageButton1.getLayoutParams();
                                    // Restore measured width and change left margin
                                    //rp.width = mButtonWidth;
                                   try {
                                       rp.leftMargin = rp.leftMargin + amountToMove;
                                       imageButton1.setLayoutParams(rp);
                                       // amountToMove = -amountToMove;
                                   }  finally{
                                       Context context = getApplicationContext();



                                   }

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { /* Do nothing */
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rp=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)imageButton1.getLayoutParams();
                                imageButton1.setLayoutParams(rp);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { /* Do nothing */ }
                            });
                            imageButton1.startAnimation(a);
```